# When do equivariant quasi-isomorphisms of chain complexes induce a quasi isomorphism on the tensor product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Suppose I have chain complexes $A,B,C,D$ where $A$ and $C$ have right $R$-module structures and $B$ and $D$ have left $R$-module structures, and that I have maps $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$ which satisfy $g(r\cdot x)=r\cdot g(x)$ and $f(x\cdot r)=f(x)\cdot r$. Suppose further that $f,g$ are quasi-isomorphisms.

**Question:** When can I conclude that $f\otimes_{R} g: A\otimes_{R} B\to C\otimes_{R} D$ also induces a quasi-isomorphism?

**Edit**: Specifically, I'm in a situation where $B$ and $D$ have field coefficients over a field $F$, and $R$ has the form $R=F[\pi]$, $A=C=F$ and the action of $F[\pi]$ on $F$ is trivial, and the map $f=\text{id}$. I feel that the fact I'm using field coefficients may simplify matters.

**Second Edit:** To clarify further, $B$ and $D$ are submodules of singular chain complexes with field coefficients. In particular, $B=K_*(\widetilde{X};F)\otimes K_*(\widetilde{X};F)\subset S_*(\widetilde{X};F)\otimes S_*(\widetilde{X};F)$ and $D=K_*(\widetilde{X}\times\widetilde{X};F)\subset S_*(\widetilde{X}\times\widetilde{X};F)$

The map $g$ is actually the cross product coming from the Kunneth theorem. Moreover, $\pi$ is  the group of deck transformations for $\widetilde{X}$ and is acting on $B$ and $D$ via the diagonal action. I hope this helps to explain my question more.

Comment: If the chain complexes are cofibrant in an appropriate model structure then this would follow from Ken Brown's lemma, but cofibrant chain complexes tend to be levelwise projective...

Comment: Take $R=k[x]$,$A=C=D=k$ and $B=k[x]\rightarrow^{\cdot x}k[x]$. Then $A\otimes C=k$ but $B\otimes D=k\rightarrow^0k$. Can you be more specific in your Edit? I do not understand what it means that B and D have field coefficients.